# R - group data by a vector of conditions and sum it up

Tags: r, break, cut

I have no idea of how to group data by a column with several conditions. I want to have a flexible slider that sets the amount of groups and R calculated the sum of the rows in order to display them in a barplot. Here is what I did and I hope someone has an idea:

I have a set of data like this:

```
print(mydata)
Deviation   Fuel
-98893        10
-98032        20
-93958        30
-68953        40
-67829        50
```

etc, etc, etc..

At the end they will be displayed in a barplot. Now I want to group the data by "Deviation". With library(shiny) I made a slider to define the amount of groups.

```
> input
[1] 4
```

So "input" gives the information that mydata has to be grouped by 4 groups. Then I need the range of "Deviation" in order to apply the groups and after that I can calculate the range of each group:

```
ABWGES <- -min(mydata$Deviation)+max(mydata$Deviation)
STEP <- round(ABWGES/input)
print(STEP)
[1] 24923
```

I tried a lot of different ways to do the next few steps, but I was unable to get my favored result. If I set the amount of groups to 4, R needs to create 4 groups. I set a name for each group in brackets to show you my result, but I wished it would be possible to name the groups out of the vector that will be generated for the brakes:

```
(1)-98893 to -73970
(2)-73969 to -49046
(3)-49045 to -24122
(4)-24121 to 802

Deviation   Fuel    group
    -98893        10    1
    -98032        20    1
    -93958        30    1
    -68953        40    2
    -67829        50    2
    -63738        60    2
    -60031        70    2
    -55063        80    2
    -54864        90    2
    -53042       100    2
    -52000       110    2
    -51000       120    2
       500       130    4
       800       140    4
```

As you can see, there is a group missing, because no number meet the requirement for group 3. So my barplot will only have 3 bars and this is annoying. It should be this instead:

```
Deviation   Fuel    group
    -98893        10    1
    -98032        20    1
    -93958        30    1
    -68953        40    2
    -67829        50    2
    -63738        60    2
    -60031        70    2
    -55063        80    2
    -54864        90    2
    -53042       100    2
    -52000       110    2
    -51000       120    2
         0         0    3
       500       130    4
       800       140    4
```

I want to perform this procedure for a lot of data, so does anyone has an idea of how to do it? P.S. I tried to use setDT for cutting the data into groups..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr` to get the missing combination

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   complete(group = full_seq(group, 1), fill = list(Deviation = 0, Fuel = 0))  
# A tibble: 15 x 3
#   group Deviation  Fuel
#   <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    -98893    10
# 2     1    -98032    20
# 3     1    -93958    30
# 4     2    -68953    40
# 5     2    -67829    50
# 6     2    -63738    60
# 7     2    -60031    70
# 8     2    -55063    80
# 9     2    -54864    90
#10     2    -53042   100
#11     2    -52000   110
#12     2    -51000   120
#13     3         0     0
#14     4       500   130
#15     4       800   140
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Deviation = c(-98893L, -98032L, -93958L, -68953L, 
-67829L, -63738L, -60031L, -55063L, -54864L, -53042L, -52000L, 
 -51000L, 500L, 800L), Fuel = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 
70L, 80L, 90L, 100L, 110L, 120L, 130L, 140L), group = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("Deviation", 
"Fuel", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L
 ))
```

Comment: @ErikSteiner  Please be specific what is going wrong.  Thanks

Comment: I am fighting with the post mechanic of replying. I used to use Enter for a new column, but stackoverflow is making me crazy..

Comment: I used library(data.table) to apply a group to all rows:
setDT(mydata)[ ...

Then group_by and sum up:
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  groups Abweichung BW_Gesamt
  <fctr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1      1    -290883        60
2      2    -526520       720
3      4       1300       270

Now I want to implement your suggestion:
# Add missing groups
mydata %>% 
  complete(groups = full_seq(groups, 1), fill = list(Abweichung = 0, BW_Gesamt = 0))

This will give me an error message:
Error in UseMethod("full_seq") : 
  no applicable method for 'full_seq' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: Please read this for better formatting. I am new to stackoverflow and formatting and limitation is really annoying:
https://pastebin.com/WMK8i4iT

Comment: @ErikSteiner  I think you have a ``factor` class.  Please convert to `integer` i.e. `df1 %>% mutate(group = as.integer(as.character(group))) %>% complete(group, ...`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! :D Wuhuuu!
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  groups Abweichung BW_Gesamt
   <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1      1    -290883        60
2      2    -526520       720
3      3          0         0
4      4       1300       270